# Upper bound and lower bound of the sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Sequence :

$ S =  \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} , x > \frac{1}{2}, x \in Q$

I tried to find the upper bound by the adding $x=$ $\frac{1}{2} $and what I got is $\frac{4}{5}$. And for the lower bound when $x$ increases that sequence converge to zero right? So I thought that would be $0$. But answer is not $0$. I cannot understand why.

So please if someone can help me to find the upper bound and lower of given sequence.

Comment: Why is the answer not zero ?

Comment: I don't know why. My answer for that lower bound was 0 and that was marked as incorrect by the person who checked answers

Comment: Zero is correct.

Comment: Is my upper bound correct too?

Comment: Yes, the upper bound is 4/5.

Comment: Perhaps what was incorrect was the proof and not the answer ... The upper bound is correct too

Comment: $Q$ is the set of rationnals here, right ?

Comment: Thanks guys. @Astyx Yes. But the proof is correct. He just have put a right on proof but not in answers.

Comment: What is $Q$. If you really want to tak about sequence, I would probably expect $x\in\mathbb N$.